# run process on AspNetCore Applications without timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm a beginner in `AspNet Core`. I want to run some process on background without it timing out. Some parts of the process must run recursively and other parts run daily (for index data in lucene search engine).

Now I am using an action controller that run on head of every request, but some processes end with a timeout status.

As a workaround, I set `HttpRequest` timeout to a long time, but that is not a good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must use BackGround Process that implemented of IHostedService interface. like this:

```
public abstract class BackgroundService : IHostedService, IDisposable
    {
        private Task _executingTask;
        private readonly CancellationTokenSource _stoppingCts =
                                                       new CancellationTokenSource();

        protected abstract Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken);

        public virtual Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // Store the task we're executing
            _executingTask = ExecuteAsync(_stoppingCts.Token);

            // If the task is completed then return it,
            // this will bubble cancellation and failure to the caller
            if (_executingTask.IsCompleted)
            {
                return _executingTask;
            }

            // Otherwise it's running
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public virtual async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // Stop called without start
            if (_executingTask == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                // Signal cancellation to the executing method
                _stoppingCts.Cancel();
            }
            finally
            {
                // Wait until the task completes or the stop token triggers
                await Task.WhenAny(_executingTask, Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite,
                                                              cancellationToken));
            }
        }

        public virtual void Dispose()
        {
            _stoppingCts.Cancel();
        }
    }
```